# Recycle a Macbook Pro into an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I recently bought a new Retina Macbook Pro and I would like to know I could in some way recycle the old one into a external display.

So is there some way to use a Macbook Pro as an external monitor?

I know I could use [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html), but I'd prefer a "wired" solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use target display mode and a hook the two together using your Thunderbolt port (on new Retina) and mini-displayport on old macbook.

See more here: [Target Display Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4469?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Target display mode only applies to iMacs, and it will not work with MacBook Pros.